# How would I be able to open google maps when I press a button in my app?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-maps, apple-maps

I have this app and I want to use google maps or apple maps to open when the user presses a button in my app. How would I be able to do this? Is there like a link to the maps that opens the app or is it something else? If you can point me in the right direction it would be really helpful. Thanks! I have the button set up below like this:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in (touches ) {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

    if node.name == "openMaps" {

     //code to open google maps or apple maps....

    }
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use this:

```
if node.name == "openMaps" {
    let customURL = "comgooglemaps://"

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: customURL)) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: customURL))
    }
    else {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Google maps not installed", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        var ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(ok)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated:true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

You can find more info about the google maps URL scheme [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme?hl=en)

Edit: You must add a key to your `info.plist` for this to work.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>googlechromes</string>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

Edit: Per updated [Google Maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#step_7_declare_the_url_schemes_used_by_the_api) added "googlechromes" to plist above also.

Comment: This will not work for iOS9. you will probably get this warning: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme comgooglemaps". You need also to list your schemes LSApplicationQueriesSchemes

Comment: Is there another way to do it instead?

Comment: I get that error @LeoDabus said is there another way to do it without getting the error.

Comment: I checked and it says you have to whitelist it in the info.plist file in xcode. How would I do this?

Comment: @coding22 Edited the answer to fix this.

Comment: how would you just get the current location from google maps and return to your app.  like tapping share location on some apps.

Answer (score 10):

At button click (in action) call function "directions()" with following code :

```
func directions() {
    // if GoogleMap installed
    if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:
            "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(Float(event.addressLat)!),\(Float(event.addressLong)!)&directionsmode=driving")! as URL)

    } else {
        // if GoogleMap App is not installed
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:
            "https://maps.google.com/?q=@\(Float(event.addressLat)!),\(Float(event.addressLong)!)")! as URL)
    }
}
```

Edit your info.plist for LSApplicationQueriesSchemes :

[image]

Hope will help!