# iOS application unable to query for scheme "comgooglemaps", although i have added "comgooglemaps" in LSApplicationQuery in info plist

Tags: ios

Getting this error - "This app is not allowed to query for scheme comgooglemaps.Even though i have added "comgooglemaps" in LSApplicationQuery.

Even i have also added "googlechromes" and google map is also installed on iPhone. Still i am getting this error everytime. Please help me with it.

**Complete Error -**

-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "comgooglemaps://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme comgooglemaps"
2018-08-24 12:31:58.882862+0530 BrotherToBrother[934:253238] Can't use comgooglemaps://

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I be able to open google maps when I press a button in my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772727/how-would-i-be-able-to-open-google-maps-when-i-press-a-button-in-my-app)

Answer (score 27):

You need add comgooglemaps in your plist of project info

[image]

Comment: the key is renamed into "Queried URL Schemes"

Answer (score 4):

The regular adding scheme to info.plist doesn't work I don't know why. But finally I found a way by using info.plist source code

1- Right click on info.plist

2- Open source code

3- Copy the following code:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

After changing a way it works for me. hopefully answer be useful for you

Answer (score 2):

For those who still having this problem like me, I actually faced the same problem and the reason was I only add **comgooglemaps** to plist.

We have to add both **comgooglemaps** and **googlechromes** to the plist file like below.

[image]